# Syntax for combining mid and if functions in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am attempting to combine the if and mid functions in excel. If a value in a specific cell is true, then return the first six characters from another cell; otherwise return nothing. The following are the options I have tried:

- `=if(AA2=TRUE), MID(Y2,1,5), "")`
- `=if(AA2=TRUE), MID(Y2,1,5), ""))`
- `=if(mid(AA2=True), (Y2, 1, 5), "")`

Could someone point out the errors in this syntax? I am new to programming and any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You close the parentheses too soon. Instead of

```
=if(AA2=TRUE), MID(Y2,1,5), "")
```

Try

```
=if((AA2=TRUE), MID(Y2,1,5), "")
```

Comment: Rather use `=IF(AA2, MID(Y2,1,6), "")`. This assumes that `AA2` contains a boolean value.

Comment: @Werner - you are right. I was showing "the minimum change needed to turn this into working code", not "the best way to do this". But yes, `(AA2 = TRUE)` is equivalent to `AA2`. It could be argued that the former is more readable; but without doubt your formulation is correct, and more compact. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I encountered this particular combination of 2 functions. It's this syntax:

```vb
=IF(ISBLANK([@emailBody]);1;MID(F2;B2;7))
```